# Сделать line-height: normal для блоков кода

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Если использовать в блоках с кодом символы псевдографики, то вертикальные линии получаются прерывистыми:

If I use pseudographics in code blocks, vertical lines are discontinuous:

[image: скриншот с прерывистыми линиями]

Это происходит из-за того, что вычисленное значение `line-height` составляет 
`16.9px`.
Если поменять его на `normal`, например, таким образом:

It happens because of calculated `line-height` equal to `16.9px`.
If it would be changed to `normal`, for example via following css rule:

```
.prettyprint {
  line-height: normal;
}
```

то всё станет хорошо:

everything will be fine:

[image: скриншот с normal]

Пример / example: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/783704/178988

```
┌─────┬────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│name │ role   │ Home             │ Work             │
├─────┼────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│Jake │ Author │ +7 987 654 HO ME │                  │
│John │ Admin  │ +7 123 456 HO ME │ +7 123 456 WO RK │
│Petr │ User   │                  │ +7 000 000 WO RK │
└─────┴────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```